# Tomcat 6/7, Java 8: Can't compile JSP: [various types] cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, java-8

**NOTE WELL: THIS QUESTION DOES NOT INVOLVE ECLIPSE!**

I'm using Maven on the command line. Attempting to use the Tomcat7 plugin's run-war goal results in

> Oct 11, 2016 11:11:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file The type
>   java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced
>   from required .class files
>
> An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file The type
>   java.util.regex.Pattern cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files
>
> An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /header.jsp The type
>   java.nio.CharBuffer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced
>   from required .class files

(there are a bunch more lines like this)

This code has worked in the past without any trouble, and I can't fathom how such fundamental classes "could not be resolved."

Using the Tomcat6 plugin fails just as badly, but the failure is deferred to the point where the JSP is first invoked rather than at start time.

I suspect this has something to do with Java8, as that has been mentioned in the answers to similar questions involving Eclipse (ONCE AGAIN: Eclipse is NOT involved here), but I have no idea what the corrective action is. We can't simply back down to java 7, as there are a ton of dependencies compiled at target 1.8 that can't be reasonably recompiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to upgrade the tomcat7 plugin from version 2.0 to 2.2.